# 4 P-FET HBridge

Tags: h-bridge, pmos

The other day I got a reel of 800 P MOSFETs, my workplace threw out, as the entire company is relocating. 800 are quite some, and I need to build me a couple of HBridges anyway, so "joy, oh joy!"
Unfortunately the joy did not last forever, since I cannot figure out how to make a HBridge with only four P MOSFETs and other discrete components.
I have made HBridges with 2xP + 2xN and with 4xN, but I get stuck with 4xP.

Therefore: Does anybody know of a HBridge design of only 4xP channel MOSFETs and other discrete components?

Comment: Just discretes? Tricky... You need two different drive voltages for the 'top' and 'bottom' FETs if they're both PFETs. [Here's](http://www.learn-c.com/experiment7.htm) a (non-discrete) example.

Comment: Just take the 4xNFET design and invert all of the voltage and component polarities. The problem is that you won't find any commercial ICs to help you because *nobody* builds H-bridges with PFETs only; it's more efficient (and no more complicated) to use NFETs.

Comment: Link to the datasheet of the parts you have.

Comment: Use reversed schottky diodes in place of 2 FETs, as passive switches that just act opposite to their corresponding FETs.  Alternatively, drive 2 PFETs via inverters

Answer (score 1):

When all you have is a hammer, you try to consider all problems nails.  However, contorting all problems to the solution at hand is not always a good idea.

First, you need to understand the capabilities of the particular PFET you have.  Then you have to see if it is appropriate for some kind of usable H bridge.  If so, I'd probably use these PFETs for the high side switches only, and get other parts for the low side switches.  That means you'll only use 2 of your free PFETs per H bridge.  Oh well.

If you want a high current H bridge, you can parallel several of your free PFETs for the high side switches.  Again, link to the datasheet of these PFETs and tell us the requirements of whatever you want to drive with these H bridges.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit**: Previous design was a fluke.  Voltages were too low and transistors didn't work properly.  As Dave Tweed has suggested, a negative voltage would be necessary for this to work properly.  Here is one such design.

You haven't stated whether negative voltages would be available to you, so this may or may not be impractical.

In this way, the transistors have **minimal power loss**, as you can see with 11.36V delivered to the load.  The upper PMOS has about 200mV across it, while the lower has about 400mV across it when they are on.

[image]

Comment: The problem with your design is that the lower two MOSFETs won't be fully turned on unless you can drive their gates below ground (to a negative voltage). Otherwise, they'll always have their threshold voltage across them, wasting power.

Comment: @DaveTweed   How do you figure that? Each of those MOSFETs has a threshold of -1.5. According to the simulation, their Vgs when turned on is -3.97.  As the current ramps up through the motor, the gate voltage is at 0, and the source rises from 3.5 to 3.97, giving -3.97 Vgs

Comment: It would be appreciated if you explained your comment and proved your stance because this seems to be the reason for the down-votes and as of currently, the simulation disagrees with you.  In any case, the author asked for a working solution, not the best or most power efficient one.

Comment: If you have Vgs = -3.97 V, then you have only 1.03 V across the "motor" (minus whatever the drop across the upper PFET is). This is not a useful design, let alone an efficient one.

Comment: @DaveTweed The reason the circuit behaves that way is because of how horribly inaccurate I have modeled the motor in that circuit.  It should be modeled by a resistor and an inductor, not just an inductor. Hence why the voltage drops to 0 across the "motor", as it would with any inductor.  So this isn't a flaw of the design

Comment: Why don't you try it with just a resistor as a load and see what kind of results you get? Keep things as simple as possible until you understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: @DaveTweed You're right, the transistors won't operate correctly in that configuration.  Since the author didn't specify whether he could use negative voltages, I've updated this with a design that does work with negative voltages

Comment: OK, that works as long as the total supply voltage (positive to negative) is less than the maximum Vgs that the FETs can tolerate. There are very few FETs that can tolerate 24V.